# How to extends Abstract Inner Class in java

Tags: java, inner-classes

I confused if

```
Abstract Class A{method();method2();}
```

And Other `Class B` Which Have Inner `Class C`

```
Class B{Abstract Class C{method(){//body}}}
```

And now Question is how to extends Class C b/C Abstract Class must be extends else
this is Unused class.

Comment: Do you need to extend an inner class?

Comment: Please take some time to write your code snippets more realistically - with proper formatting, and paying attention to casing.

Comment: (And in general, please rewrite your question to be clearer - I *think* I know what you're asking, but it's very far from clear.)

Answer (score 11):

First, let's make it simpler - this has nothing to do with Android directly, and you don't need your `A` class at all. Here's what you want:

```
class Outer {
    abstract class Inner {
    }
}

class Child extends Outer.Inner {
}
```

That doesn't compile, because when you create an instance of `Child` you need to provide an instance of `Outer` to the `Inner` constructor:

```
Test.java:6: error: an enclosing instance that contains Outer.Inner is required
class Child extends Outer.Inner {
^
1 error
```

There are two options that can fix this:

- If you don't need to refer to an implicit instance of `Outer` from `Inner`, you could make `Inner` a static nested class instead:

  ```
  static abstract class Inner {
  }
  ```
- You could change `Child` to accept a reference to an instance of `Outer`, and use *that* to call the `Inner` constructor, which uses slightly surprising syntax, but works:

  ```
  Child(Outer outer) {
      // Calls Inner constructor, providing
      // outer as the containing instance
      outer.super();
  }
  ```

Note that these are alternatives - you should pick which one you want based on whether or not the inner class really *needs* to be an inner class.

Comment: `outer.super()` is in fact so surprising that I though I was looking at a typo ... but it is not ... I am totally not getting it?

Comment: @JoD.: It's consistent with how you can specify the instance to use for a containing class. If `Inner` weren't abstract, you could use `Outer x = new Outer(); Outer.Inner y = x.new Outer.Inner();`

Comment: I understood your second example: first time seeing something like this, but no surprises there. However, I don't see how it relates to `outer.super()`. I tried looking up in JLS, didn't find, and when I find, I am sure that I would still not be able to relate to it. I have this question tagged for now, and it seems that I will have to revisit several times - like a chanting I have to practice before it takes effect.

Comment: @JoD.: It relates to `outer.super()` because both are providing the outer class reference to the inner class. It's specced in section 8.8.7.1: "Qualified superclass constructor invocations begin with a Primary expression or an ExpressionName. They allow a subclass constructor to explicitly specify the newly created object's immediately enclosing instance with respect to the direct superclass (§8.1.3). This may be necessary when the superclass is an inner class."

Comment: uh - I suddenly understood with the notion from the JLS that the prefix is just an instance of the enclosing class - wasn't that difficult after all, just had to - you know - read it a few times. It was exactly in the quote you provided. Thanks. Leaves me to wonder though why you would ever consider to design in such a way ...

Answer (score 1):

You simply extend it

```
class B{abstract class C{abstract void method();}}
class D extends B{
    class E extends C{
        void method(){
            System.out.println("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

Or slightly more complicated without extending outer class

```
class B{abstract class C{abstract void method();}}
public class F extends B.C{
  F(B b){
      b.super();
  }
  void method(){
      System.out.println("Hello World");
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
      B b = new B();
      F f = new F(b);
      f.method();
  }
}
```

Comment: That only works because `D` extends `B` - there's no indication that the OP wants to extend the enclosing class, or have a second inner class at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet that is correct, wanted to contribute simple example. BTW what is that OP?